# mongodb query update in php using laravel framework

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

I'am trying to update the colletion with new email id. The code is as follows

```
   $emails=json_encode($requestparams['Email']);

    DB::collection('BACKUP_RESTORE_LOG')
->Where('MobileNo',$requestparams['MobileNo'])
->Where('ClientCode',$requestparams['ClientCode'])
->update('$push' ,array('Emails', $emails));
```

My collection will be like these

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("582eda6daa4a810620f8f3c5"),
    "MobileNo" : "944xxxx41",
    "ClientCode" : "xxx",
    "Emails" : [ 
        "omsdsd@gmail.com"
    ],
    "CreatedDate" : ISODate("2016-11-22T06:08:29.004Z")
}
```

I need to add email in Emails array.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't why my question is wrong, but i found solution. my work done by removing update and added push as below.

```
DB::collection('BACKUP_RESTORE_LOG')
->Where('MobileNo',$requestparams['MobileNo'])
->Where('ClientCode',$requestparams['ClientCode'])
->push('Emails' ,array($requestparams['Email']));
```